# Using Contains in NetSuite saved search to search for one or more keywords

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

What do you use as a seperator when using contain in saved search criteria in NetSuite? For example:
Formula (Text)  contains apple**SEPERATOR?**banana.
So I want the seperator here to act as OR.

I tried OR, %, "", * .
I am not sure if I tried the above correctly. When I use has keywords I use Text1 OR Text2. However, when using contains the same way it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the UI your options are to either check 'use expressions' and set this up as an `or` clause or use a formula. I tend to do this as formula numeric = 1 and then the formula:

```sql
case when INSTR('keyword1', {fieldid}) > 0 then 1 
when INSTR('keyword2', {fieldid} > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have many keywords that I would want to include. is there an alternative to INSTR where I can copy paste bunch of keywords?